# how to calculate the difference of two item template bind values in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not sure if i have chosen the right words to ask the question. However, Here is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvJobCostList" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgvJobCostList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Valid From">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRateEffectiveFrom" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RateEffectiveFrom") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipper">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%--<asp:Label ID="lblShipperName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ShipperName") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                            <%--<asp:Label ID="lblShipperName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Shipper.ShipperName") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblShipperName" runat="server" Text='<%# ((BOJobInfo)Container.DataItem).oShipper.ShipperName %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Consignee">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%--<asp:Label ID="lblConsigneeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ConsigneeName") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblConsigneeName" runat="server" Text='<%# ((BOJobInfo)Container.DataItem).oConsignee.ConsigneeName %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Income">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalIncome" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TotalIncome") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cost">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalCost" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TotalCost") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CM1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalCM1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TotalIncome" - "TotalCost") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

My Problem is
1. I want to calculate the difference of Income and Cost and display the result in CM1 template.
2. I want to format the date of "RateEffectiveFrom" as "dd-MMM-yyyy" which is currently showing something similar to "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM".
Please Help as you did before. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do without RowDataBound you can do as follow:

```
<label id="cm1Label"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TotalIncome") - DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TotalCost")%></label>
```

Or write a small public static function at server which will give you difference based on passed values

```
Text='<%# GetDifference(Eval("TotalIncome"),Eval("TotalCost"))%>'
```

for date you can do something like this:

```
'<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("RateEffectiveFrom")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the server side RowDataBound event for grid view

Find the template controls using e.Row.FindControl e.g.

```
protected void dgvJobCostList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    Label lblRateEffectiveFrom = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblRateEffectiveFrom"));

    //Use following line to change the date format in RowDataBound after finding the control

    lblRateEffectiveFrom .Text = lblRateEffectiveFrom .Text.ToString(dd-MMM-yyyy")
       //do what ever you want to do here using the value of your label
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **@Rahul R**., although your provided code samples needed little modification, it these surely gave me the idea to solve the problem. So I will mark your answer as "Answer". Here is the code I am currently using

**For Problem 1.**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Income">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalIncome" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TotalIncome") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cost">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalCost" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TotalCost") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CM1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalCM1" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TotalIncome")) - Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TotalCost"))%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**For Problem 2.**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Valid From">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRateEffectiveFrom" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RateEffectiveFrom", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Also thanks to Rana and Rizvi for sharing your ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way,

```
    public decimal GetOrders(decimal order)
    {
        totalOrders += order;
        return order;
    }
    public decimal GetOrdersTotal()
    {
        return totalOrders;
    }
```

And,

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <%# GetOrders(decimal.Parse(Eval("OrderTotal").ToString())).ToString("N2")%>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<%# GetOrdersTotal().ToString("N2")%>
</FooterTemplate>
```

For the date, you can use same thing, or use format functions from grid property